# How i can get Image/file Extension from uploaded image using _fileUploaderFactory in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, file-upload, uploader, file-uploader

I am Working on **custom Module** In **Magento 2** I m trying to `upload image` to `database` using **fileUploaderFactory**.

```
try {
        $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'image']);
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        $path = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('backgroundimage/');
        $filename=$data['title'].$data['date_from'];
        $filename = str_replace(' ', '_', $filename);
        $uploader->save($path,$filename);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addError(__($e->getMessage()));
    }
```

File is Upload in `database` but i m not getting `File extension` that is why file is not showing in my `GRID list`

Anyone please Guide

Comment: $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'Your_Column_Name']) check it

Comment: I wanna Check whether it is jpg/Png/jpeg

Comment: try to comment this line `$filename = str_replace(' ', '_', $filename);` and check

Comment: $ext=pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);